# Lucene Spellchecker ranking suggestions strangely

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net, spell-checking

I'm using the Spellchecker in the Lucene.NET contrib NuGet package v3.0.3.

The spellchecker index is created using  `_spellChecker.IndexDictionary(new SpellChecker.Net.Search.Spell.LuceneDictionary(reader, "Name"));`

The problem I'm having is (I'm assuming) that due to the way shingles/n-grams work, running `_spellChecker.SuggestSimilar("Wiess")` does not score "Weiss" very high. "Witness", "Wireless", and "Wills" score higher than "Weiss".

It seems like "Weiss" should be scored higher than "Wireless". Is there a way I can tweak this to get that result?

Comment: I think it may be related to the language the spellchecker uses? (sorry don't know lucene)

Comment: The spellchecker is using words I provide (names), so the language shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question led to another question. See answer: [Lucene SpellChecker Prefer Permutations or special scoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689812/lucene-spellchecker-prefer-permutations-or-special-scoring/13692666#13692666)

Many thanks to femtoRgon for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided what is DOES return, so I'm assuming you simply don't like what it gives, rather than that it gives you nothing.

In Lucene Documentation there isn't a SuggestSimilar method taking 1 argument.  I believe this is because you should never rely on just one result, per the API, min reference to the number of suggestions argument:

"I.e. if numSug == 1, don't count on that suggestion being the best one.  Thus, you should set this value to **at least 5** for a good suggestion."

I assume you can provide that second argument.  Try setting it higher and see what you get.

EDIT--

Okay.  I see.  Perhaps a simple Levenshtein distance style algorithm would be more what you are looking for.  Lucene 4.0 provides an (experimental) new spellchecker for that: [DirectSpellChecker](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/DirectSpellChecker.html).  Also, a simple [FuzzyQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html) would, I believe, do the job as well.  Either of these approaches will remove aspects of the SpellChecker algorithm, effectively simplifying it, and you may find your results, on the whole, get worse.

Note:

- "Wiess"  "Weiss"     distance 2
- "Wiess"  "Witness"   distance 2
- "Wiess"  "Wireless"  distance 3
- "Wiess"  "Wills"     distance 2

So, actually, that might not get you much there.  You could probably write a filter preferring results of equal length to the query, but that won't help distinguish Wills.  That one you might have to live with.

Comment: Sorry for the original omission of details. I was using 5 suggestions at first, but "Weiss" appears 32nd at the moment. It appears Lucene.NET does not contain DirectSpellChecker yet. I'm trying the FuzzyQuery and will return with details. Thanks.

Comment: The FuzzyQuery seems useful, but also is not giving me the results I want. I'm going to try writing a filter that prefers *permutations*.